# Separate text with regex and writing to unique columns

Tags: python, regex

I have a CSV file with one column (Column A), in it contains a list of items formatted as a string.

1 - Item A

1 - Item B

1 - Item C

The actual string, less Excel formatting is **1 - Item A1 - Item B1 - Item C**...as there are no spaces after the Item name ends.

I'm looking to write a function in python that isolates each of those Items and writes to separate columns such that New Column 1 contains just Item A, New Column 2 contains just Item B and so on...

1 (space) dash (space) consistently marks the start of a new Item. Although it could start with any number 1-9. After the Item letter (A,B,C etc) there is no space.

Additionally, there could be anywhere from 1-10 items in a string, so to be safe I'd like to create ten new columns and map to those as needed.

Any help with the regex/python combo would be much appreciated. A little out of practice...

Comment: Like this? `\d - Item [A-Z]` https://regex101.com/r/XlnEJs/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string in the form of "1 - Item A1 - Item B1 - Item C", where the ones could be any other single-digit but the digit followed by a space, hyphen (not the same as a dash by the way) and another space is what separates items, then you could to this:

```
import re

s = '1 - Item A5 - Item B7 - Item C8 - Item D'
m = re.split('\d - ', s)

print(m[1:])
# Output: ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C', 'Item D']
```

If you want a matching list of headers for this, you could do:

```
headers = ["New Column %d" % i for i in range(1,len(m)) ]
# This gives you ['New Column 1', 'New Column 2', 'New Column 3', 'New Column 4']
```

Now you could create a new CSV file and write `','.join(headers)` for the first row and `','.join(m[1:])` for the second row.